# Filtering Object Array to only contain Key using Lodash

Tags: javascript, filtering, lodash

I have the following object array:

```
 {
   running: false,
   swimming: false,
   drawing: true
  }
```

I want to filter the object array with only those that have false properties. From there I want to get only the keys of the array.

eg.

```
 [running, swimming]
```

I have the first part of removing values that have truth booleans through the following:

```
var filtered = _.pick(hobbies, function(value, key) {return !value;});
```

What would be the best way to "flatten" the current array so that I only have the key values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Lodash `_.keys()` function provides precisely what you are asking for:

```js
var hobbies = {
    running: false,
    swimming: false,
    drawing: true
};

var filtered = _.keys(_.pick(hobbies, function(value) {return !value;}));

console.log(filtered);

// alternate approach using chain notation
var keys = _
    .chain(hobbies)
    .pick(v => !v)
    .keys();

console.log(keys);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.9.3/lodash.js"></script>
```

Note that in Lodash 4.x, `_.pick()` has changed and you should instead use `_.pickBy()` aboce.

Answer (score 3):

As it is possible with pure `JavaScript`, then I suggesting you to do it using `Object.keys` and `Array.prototype.filter`

```js
var obj = {
  running: false,
  swimming: false,
  drawing: true
};

var items = Object.keys(obj).filter(k => !obj[k]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
```